# Performance issue with Tensorflow model server on CPU in comparison with Tensorflow model inference

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I observe performance issue for CPU with Tensorflow model server. It doubles the time for inference in comparison to raw Tensorflow model inference. Both built with MKL for CPU only.

Code to reproduce: https://github.com/BogdanRuzh/tf_model_service_benchmark

**Tensorflow MKL build:**
`bazel build --config=mkl -c opt --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-O3 //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

**Tensorflow server MKL build:**
`bazel build --config=mkl --config=opt --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-O3 tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server`

The target model is simple CNN for segmentation.

Raw Tensorflow model process an image in 0.17s.
Tensorflow model server process the same image in 0.32s.

How can I improve this performance? It's very critical for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that explonation will help you. It's said that with bad configuration tensorflow with intel optimizations may have worse performance then clear build https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1272#issuecomment-477878180

You may try to configure parameters of batching (with config file and --enable_batching parameter) https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/batching

And set (inter/intra)_op_parallelism_threads.

Additionaly, MKL has it's own flags for improving performance https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview#tuning_mkl_for_the_best_performance

Answer (score 0):

If you need better performance, I'd recommend trying [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html). It optimizes the inference time by e.g. graph pruning and fusing some operations. OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU. However, I assume you have Intel CPU as you compiled TensorFlow with MKL support.

[Here](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html) are some performance benchmarks for various models and CPUs.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Tensorflow model to OpenVINO unless you have fancy custom layers. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, which is a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (just change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --input_shape "[1, 3, 224, 224]" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device e.g. CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what is the best choice for you, just use AUTO.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="CPU")

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

There is even [OpenVINO Model Server](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/model_server) which is very similar to Tensorflow Serving.

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.